# PostgreSQL 13 - Performance Improvement to get distinct data from table with date range

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-administration

I am using PostgreSQL 13 and has intermediate level experience with PostgreSQL.

I have a table named `audit_log`. Whenever a user logs in into the system, I store that activity in this table.

Below is my table structure, followed by datatype and index access method

```
  Column     |            Data Type        |     Index name            | Idx Access Type
-------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------
 id          | bigint                      |                           |
 log_time    | timestamp with time zone    |  idx_log_time             | btree
 user_id     | text                        |  idx_user_id              | btree
 customer_id | bigint                      |  idx_customer_id          | btree
 is_active   | boolean                     |  idx_is_active            | btree
 is_delete   | boolean                     |  idx_is_delete            | btree
```

I want to get unique users who are logged in into the system for a given customer in last 30 days.

There are two customers **`cust1` & `cust2`** and total records in `audit_log` table are **2,24,11,490**

For `cust1` , when I execute below query, I get **4,374** unique users who are logged in into the system in last 30 days and the execution time is **792 ms**.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM audio_log WHERE is_active=TRUE AND is_delete=FALSE AND customer_id=1 AND log_time BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-31 00:00:00'`

Please note that the total logged in users for `cust1` in last 30 days is `9,747`.

**Problem Area**

For `cust2` , when I execute below query, I get **88,568** unique users who are logged in into the system in last 30 days and the execution time is **3 sec**.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM audio_log WHERE is_active=TRUE AND is_delete=FALSE AND customer_id=2 AND log_time BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-31 00:00:00'`

Please note that the total logged in users for `cust2` in last 30 days is `4,86,519`.

**Problem**

My concern is that this query should take less than 1 sec for `cust2`. So is there any way we can optimize and reduce the execution time?

Below is Explain the query plan
[image]
Below is my pg_settings

[image]

**Tried Solutions**

1. BRIN Index
   I applied BRIN index for `log_time` column but it took even more time to execute the query
2. GROUP BY option
   I used the`GROUP BY` clause as suggested in few solutions but that also didn't improve the performance.

Please guide. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have to add new conditon which will not consider given list of user_id in distinct count.

Below query takes 1.2 Sec for execution.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM audio_log WHERE is_active=TRUE AND is_delete=FALSE AND customer_id=2 AND log_time BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-31 00:00:00'`

When i used not in above query , it takes more time to execute. below is my updated query.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM audio_log WHERE is_active=TRUE AND is_delete=FALSE AND customer_id=2 AND log_time BETWEEN '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-31 00:00:00' AND user_id not in ('sndka__sjkd_jask_ldkl','eydu_iehc_jksd_hcjk_hsdk')`

**Added Index**

CREATE INDEX cust_time_user ON audio_log USING BTREE
(customer_id, is_active, is_delete, log_time, user_id);

Is there any way to optimize it??

Comment: Please show text as text.  Your query plan looks very pretty.  Unfortunately, that is because all those ugly looking bits of useful information have been removed.

Comment: Please avoid updating your question after you get answers. The point of StackOverflow, and the reason many of us contribute answers, is building a library of good questions and answers. It gets confusing if the questions change after the answers. It's always OK to ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a multicolumn BTREE index.  Your query, annotated, is this.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)      -- item to deduplicate
  FROM audio_log
 WHERE is_active=TRUE               -- equality filter
   AND is_delete=FALSE              -- equality filter
   AND customer_id=1                -- most selective equality filter
   AND log_time BETWEEN             -- range filter
            '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-01-31 00:00:00'
```

In BTREE indexes, equality filters come first, then range filters, then items you want to deduplicate.  So, use this index. I named it `cust_time_user` but you can name it anything you wish.

```sql
CREATE INDEX cust_time_user ON audio_log USING BTREE
      (customer_id, is_active, is_delete, log_time, user_id);
```

Postgres can satisfy your query from this BTREE index, by random accessing the first eligible row, then scanning it sequentially to find the last eligible row.

You may have an error in your range filter: `BETWEEN` is generally unsuitable for time-range filters.  For best results use `>=` for the beginning of the range and `<` for the end of the range. You want, I believe,

```sql
   AND log_time >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'  -- earliest day
   AND log_time <  '2022-02-01 00:00:00'  -- day after the latest day
```

**Pro tip** Often it doesn't make sense to add lots of single-column indexes to tables. Indexes are most useful when designed to help satisfy queries of particular shapes. Read this for more excellent information https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Thanks.. Its worked for me **O.Jones**

But i have updated my question..